# Smoke showing in Preview, but not in finished render

Tags: rendering, particles, smoke-simulation

I've been trying to render a weapon, with a passive red smoke behind it - smoke is showing up in the layout tab and is shown when the animation is played. But when trying to render it, no smoke is shown.

The engine I'm using to render the smoke is Cycles on Experimental. I've tried baking the smoke but without success.

Comment: Please add screenshots of the viewport and rendered scene and the shader you are using on the smoke.

Comment: Do you have proper smoke material?

Answer (score 0):

Have you long enough  camera  range?  Have you changed the volumetricks number  of passes from zero? Sun is not a light source that can be  used  on smoke.  You need an other sort of  light I think. Some wild stabs  in the dark  from  a noob. :)